# Save BinaryWrite to Server Path

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am saving files to SQL Server on remote hosted server. I can upload them. But I need to download a file to the remote servers path.  The code below extracts the file but saves it to the client.

I tried replacing Response.BinaryWrite(bytes) to Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DS/sailbig.jpg") but I get an error file not found.

I simply want to extract the file I stored in sql and place it a the directory on the server so I can use it in code later, but I cannot figure it out.  Any help is appreciated, this is a hobby for me.

```
    Dim filePath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DS/")
    Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Data"), Byte())
    response.Buffer = True
    response.Charset = ""
    response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    response.ContentType = dt.Rows(0)("ContentType").ToString()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & dt.Rows(0)("FileName").ToString())
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx):

```
Dim filePath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DS/")
Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Data"), Byte())

File.WriteAllBytes(filePath & dt.Rows(0)("FileName").ToString(), bytes)
```

Comment: Super :) please check the answer as accepted if solution was useful.

Comment: yes please mark as correct.  I almost didn't try the solution because it was not marked as correct